# How to avoid dependency issue when the whole project are divided into different modules

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

Given a project, it is divided into 3 modules A, B and C. Those three modules are developed by three teams and in different repos. Moreover, A, B and C has dependency for each other. In the beginning, everything works well. Each team can imports dependency from other team and config the dependency in some file. However, let's say module A, for some refactoring reason, need to adjust the classes. The adjust may just change the dependency reference for the some classes(like move a class from 'a-folder-1' to 'a-folder-2'). When A push code, the tests would not fail because for the A's repo, there is nothing wrong. However, when B or C push code they will face dependency issue, because they are still using the old way to import the classes in A which has been refactored. The solution is quite simple, B and C just need to adjust the dependency config file to import the classes from A in proper way.

**My question is, is there any framework or tool help us to avoid this kind of issue?** For now, every time some one changed the dependency, others can only adjust their own dependency config. It is simple when the project is small but when there are many teams, this make trouble. Because every time some one wants to push new code he may face the dependency issue.

Comment: Solution - code to interfaces.

Comment: Version each build so that B and C can update the dependency on A when it's convenient.  But why are there 3 different repos for the same project?  Have 1 repo for the entire code base, with 3 maven/gradle modules.  Refactoring will force an update of the other modules (assuming build failures are not allowed to merge).

Comment: Every time B or C try to push code, they will use the lates version of A. Because there is no point to define the version for them. Different repo has its own development speed. Even they are working on the same project, when the project is really big, they do need to divided into different repos.

Answer (score 0):

**There really isn't an easy tool you can use. The only solution is good planning.**

The only way to solve these kinds of  dependency problems is to have the full API (list of classes, properties, methods) *before* the project is started. **This requires planning**, and is why software architecture and design is so important to understand.

The design of each of the three modules must be carefully planned, so that making new features does not require any major refactoring.

You could check out [semver](https://semver.org/), it's basically a systematic way of versioning things. It could help you communicate changes, especially distinguishing between breaking and non-breaking changes.

Comment: Yeah, I know the planing is important before the start of project. But most of time work in a tech company you will have no chance to join the planning meeting before the project start. When you join a team, the code has been running for years.